# SAP Java Connector (JCo) mocking/testing JCoFunction and/or JCoParameterList

Tags: java, junit, mocking, jco

I need to test a module without actually calling our SAP provider via executing a "real" `JCoFunction`.

How do I instantiate a "formally correct" `JCoFunction`?

I can even just deal with a `JCoParameterList` but just can't figure out how to instantiate it or even mock it.

Comment: Which JCo version? There are huge differences between 2 and 3!

Comment: we're using sap-jco version 3.0.0

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 1):

> The SAP Java Connector (SAP JCo) is a toolkit that allows a Java application to communicate with any SAP System.

These guys here tried to do the same, using the 3.0 version of the SAP JCo: 
[Can a JCo server simulate a SAP remote function?](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1646972)

My experience from last week is that it is not possible to create a mock SAP server to act like a `JCoDestination`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
new JCO.ParameterList()
```

Comment: Here it says that it's a class: http://www.huihoo.org/openweb/jco_api/com/sap/mw/jco/JCO.ParameterList.html

Comment: will look into that BUT for now i'm talking about com.sap.conn.jco.JCoParameterList

Comment: Where's the javadoc? Is it publically accessible?

Comment: apparently not. i'm gonna have to ask my boss to get a "SAP Service Marketplace" account. meanwhile, if anybody else already did something like this, it'd be nice to give it a look.

Comment: @NidaSahar not working on this in a long time. sorry.